# CentOS7　SSH接続できない

Tags: ssh

CentOS最新版を使っています。
SSH接続をしたく設定をあらかじめしてみました。

rootログイン禁止とパスワード認証を許可の設定をしました。

そして

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

コマンドで確認してみると

```
service:dhcpv6-client ssh
```

という表記がされていて、ファイアウォールでは許可されているみたいです。多分

そして、Windowsからsshで接続してみると、

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:5uK6VbJveXIW2lnDBsfuaGtiC2juqVyEWM/Vj2M4diY.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/hasegawaryo/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/hasegawaryo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

といわれてしまいます。

```
sed -i -e '/0.114/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

これを実行しても駄目でした。
Cyberduckからの接続はできます。
これは、何が原因でしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

リモートホストの指紋(fingerprint)が以前に接続した時のそれと異なっているため、安全のため接続がはじかれている状態です。OSを再インストールしたり、サーバの公開鍵を変更したりするとこうなることが多いです。
念のため、接続先が間違っていないか確認しましょう。

クライアント側で以下のコマンドを実行して、ホスト情報をリセットしてから改めて接続してみてください。

```
ssh-keygen -R ホスト名
```

補足すると、

> Offending ECDSA key in /home/hasegawaryo/.ssh/known_hosts:1

エラー表示によると ~/.ssh/known_hosts の1行目のホスト情報が不一致であることが分かります。
このファイルを`sed`コマンドで編集したいのであれば `sed -i -n 1d ~/.ssh/known_hosts` (1行目を削除して上書き保存) がこの場合は適切です。

ただし、先述した `ssh-keygen` コマンドを経由して known_hosts を更新するほうがファイルを直接編集するよりも簡単かつ安全です。

Comment: ssh-keygen -R ホスト名
の作業は、サーバー機から入力ですか？
それとも、SSHで接続するPCからですか？

Comment: 後者です。クライアントPCで保持しているサーバの情報をリセットさせる目的で使います。

Comment: ssh-keygen -R ホスト名を実行すれば接続できるようになりました。
助かりました。